# How to calculate a date difference in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I'm trying to generate a query that will display the date difference between a date stored in a column and the current date, but i'm getting the error:

> "Cannot call method "getTime" of null."

What function can I use to calculate this date difference in Google Cloud SQL?

Current code:

```
SELECT date, DATEDIFF(date, CURRENT_DATE()) AS daysLeft
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a mysql instance on Google Cloud.  If so try the following

```
SELECT date, DATEDIFF(date, CURDATE()) AS daysLeft
FROM table;
```

All that changed is CURDATE() instead of CURRENT_DATE()

Comment: Its not a msql instance, its a Google Cloud SQL Table. I tried your suggestion and the exact same error keeps appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the error was in another part of the code. The originally posted SQL query works perfectly fine, the problem was the model was casting the result as a date variable instead of an int.

Answer (score -1):

The `DATEDIFF` function requires [three parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
SELECT date, DATEDIFF(day, date, CURRENT_DATE()) AS daysLeft
FROM table;
```

This should return your result in days left.

Comment: Not in this case. Google Cloud SQL's DATEDIFF only requires two.